# Is there a book on logic where the metalanguage itself is symbolic and formal?

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

In many books on Logic, I see that the language used to discuss Propositional/First-order logic is not symbolic or formal. Is there one where it is?

Comment: At some point we'd need to define our nth-level metalanguage in natural language. This is inescapable.

Comment: @RyanA could we use induction to deal with that? :D

Comment: Induction as being part of what language? What you suggest seems to be a [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_hierarchy) of metalanguages.

Comment: Most mechanized proof assistants will have formalizations of logics and metatheorems about them as [examples](http://oxij.org/note/ReinventingFormalLogic/) or case studies. Logical Frameworks (LF) such as [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Case_studies) are specifically geared toward being meta-logics. However, finding an introduction to logic using these would be a bit difficult. If one didn't yet understand propositional logic, say, then they are *definitely* not going to understand the meta-logic.

Comment: @RyanA This comment piqued my curiosity. Would it be possible to define the levels of our meta language in such a way that they form a strange loop? That is, once we get to the top level, going any further brings us back to the first level again.